# Best Practice for End-to-End process of a Web Form to Database Storage

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a web form that captures `<input type="text">` and `<textarea>` elements. The back-end technologies are PHP and MySQL.

- the MySQL DB, Tables, and Columns collation are all `utf8_general_ci`
- the incoming form data is sanitized with `stripslashes($_POST['text_input'])`
- the INSERT INTO query statement looks like `SET text_storage = "mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text_input'])"`

I am seeing unreadable characters in the database as a result of variations in special characters like single apostrophes and double quotes, etc. coming through the web form.

What is the best coding practice - each step along the way - to ensure clean and readable data in the DB tables? Do I need a certain `<doctype>` or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" ... />` as well in order to capture and store clean data?

Thanks for helping me build a best practice template for clean data capture and storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute these queries before actual fetching of the records from database:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'");
```

Afterwards proceed with execution of your queries. The above queries, if course, **must be in context of your current database connection**.

The input data can be sanitized with ease with build-in PHP functions like `filter_var()` and `filter_var_array()`, however `mysql_real_escape_string()` is good solution as well.
Your HTML document must have a proper encoding in  tag: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

`mysql_real_escape_string()` escapes special characters in the unescaped_string, taking into account the current character set of the connection so that it is safe to place it in a `mysql_query()`. If binary data is to be inserted, this function must be used. The function calls MySQL's library function `mysql_real_escape_string`, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: `\x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a`.

Comment: Ok @budiony, I'll add that. But if my DB/Tables/Columns are all set to collation utf8, what is the significance of your 2 pre-queries?

Comment: Believe me, it has significant impact on returned result set. This thing plagued me long time until I manually changed these parameters runtime before every query.

Comment: Thanks @budiony. I implemented your queries and they cleaned everything right up. Awesome!